# Django: Error during template rendering

Tags: django

Tengo un error que no consigo dar con él:

NoReverseMatch at y Error during template rendering:

http://127.0.0.1:8000/blog/

[image: Captura del error]

[Enlace a GitHub](https://github.com/barkalez/catataxo/tree/master/catataxo)

Comment: Publica aquí la parte relacionada del archivo `urls.py` y si lo consideras necesaria la vista que procesa esa URL. Usa el botón `{ }` para formatear tu código.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El formato que estas usando para la url no es el correcto, mira:

```
# definición en urls.py
 url(r'^blog/post/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.post_detail, name="post_detail"),
# Uso en post_list.html
<h1><a href="{% url 'post_detail' post.pk %}">{{ post.title }}</a></h1>
```

Es buena practica agregar el atributo name a tus urls, combinando esto con los namespace puedes identificar las urls de mejor manera.

Cuando tengas problemas con las urls puedes hacer esto en la shell para obtener mas información:

```
>>> from django.urls import reverse
>>> reverse('post_detail', args=[str(self.id)])
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, solucionaste mi problema.

Answer (score 0):

Necesitas añadir esa url en tu archivo urls.py y crear la vista que responda a esa url.

Ambas deben recibir el parametro 'pk'

Saludos.